# Create and Save File on Client Side - Angular

Tags: angular

Using angular 8, I would like to create below directory structure and let the user download it as a zip;

```
- folder1
-- file1.txt
- folder2
-- file2.txt
readme.txt
```

I know how to create an individual file using Blob in angular like [this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-blob-file-download) but I am not sure how to;

1. Create folders and above directory structure?
2. Zip the directory and download for the user as single zip file?

all on client side in browser without using the backend API

Comment: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/ run the example

Comment: this is awesome! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a stackblitz as an example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ommhs

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as JSZip from 'jszip';
import fileSaver from 'file-saver';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  createZip() {
    const zip = new JSZip.default();
    // create a file
    zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n");
    // create a file and a folder
    zip.file("nested/hello.txt", "Hello World\n");
    zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
      .then(function(content) {
        // see FileSaver.js
         fileSaver.saveAs(content, "example.zip");
    });
  }

}
```